# Limit drag area each node d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an application of d3.js where I need to limit drag area of each node by circle / rectangle. This drag area may be static for each node, may be included in its json data. 
Here http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/5wssqqdw/1/ I found an example but it does not fill my requirement.

What I want like this:

[image]

Here is my example where I need to do this stuff.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" 
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body{
 background:url(images/bg.jpg) repeat;
}
 svg{
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
}
.link{
 stroke: #51565b;
 stroke-width:20; 
 stroke-opacity: 1;
 
}
  </style>
  <script>
   var width = 800,
   height = 600

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width", width)
   .attr("height", height);


 var force = d3.layout.force()
   .gravity(1)
   .linkDistance(function (d) {
   return d.distance;
 })
 .charge(-40000)
 .size([width, height]);

 var datajson = {
    "nodes": [{
     "name": "a",
     "node_id": "10",
     "group": 2,
  "node_img" : "http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog"
   }, {
     "name": "b",
     "group": 1,
  "node_id": "11",
  "node_img" : "http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog"
   }, {
     "name": "c",
     "group": 1,
  "node_id": "12",
  "node_img" : "http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog"
   }
   ],
   "links": [{
     "source": 0,
     "target": 1,
     "value": 1,
     "distance": 400
   }, {
     "source": 1,
     "target": 2,
     "value": 2,
     "distance": 300
   }, {
     "source": 2,
     "target": 0,
     "value": 3,
     "distance": 300
   }]
 }

 var numNodes = datajson.nodes.length
 var r = 20;
 datajson.nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
   node.x = width/2  + r * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / numNodes)
   node.y = height/2 + r * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / numNodes)
 })

 force
   .nodes(datajson.nodes)
   .links(datajson.links)
   .start();

 var drag = force.drag()
   .on("drag", dblclick);

 var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
   .data(datajson.links)
   .enter().append("line")
   .attr("class", "link");

 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
   .data(datajson.nodes)
   .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", function(d) { return "node "+"class_"+d.node_id})
   .call(force.drag);

 
    //circle
 var circle = node.append("circle")
 .attr("r", 55)
 .attr("id", function(d) { return d.node_id })
 .style("fill", function (d) { return 'rgba(81,86,91,1)'; })
 .attr("class", function(d) { return "circle circle_"+d.node_id });
 
 //image
 node.append("image")
   .attr("x", -37)
   .attr("y", -37)
   .attr("width", 75)
   .attr("height", 75)
   .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    return d.node_img;
   });
   
 force.on("tick", function() {
   link.attr("x1", function(d) {
       return d.source.x;
     })
     .attr("y1", function(d) {
       return d.source.y;
     })
     .attr("x2", function(d) {
       return d.target.x;
     })
     .attr("y2", function(d) {
       return d.target.y;
     });

   node.attr("transform", function(d) {
     return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
   });
 });


 function dblclick(d) {

 }
 
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background: url(images/bg.jpg) repeat;
    }
    
    svg {
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .link {
      stroke: #51565b;
      stroke-width: 20;
      stroke-opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var width = 800,
      height = 600

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .gravity(1)
      .linkDistance(function(d) {
        return d.distance;
      })
      .charge(-40000)
      .size([width, height]);

    var datajson = {
      "nodes": [{
        "name": "a",
        "node_id": "10",
        "group": 2,
        "node_img": "http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog",
        "drag_radius": 150
      }, {
        "name": "b",
        "group": 1,
        "node_id": "11",
        "node_img": "http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog",
        "drag_radius": 200
      }, {
        "name": "c",
        "group": 1,
        "node_id": "12",
        "node_img": "http://loremflickr.com/320/240/dog",
        "drag_radius": 100
      }],
      "links": [{
        "source": 0,
        "target": 1,
        "value": 1,
        "distance": 400
      }, {
        "source": 1,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 2,
        "distance": 300
      }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 0,
        "value": 3,
        "distance": 300
      }]
    }

    var numNodes = datajson.nodes.length
    var r = 20;
    datajson.nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
      node.x = width / 2 + r * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * i / numNodes)
      node.y = height / 2 + r * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * i / numNodes)
    })

    force
      .nodes(datajson.nodes)
      .links(datajson.links)
      .start();

    var drag = force.drag()
      .on("drag", drag)
      .on("dragstart", dragstart)
      .on("dragend", dragend);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(datajson.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(datajson.nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "node " + "class_" + d.node_id
      })
      .call(force.drag);


    //circle
    var circle = node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 55)
      .attr("id", function(d) {
        return d.node_id
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return 'rgba(81,86,91,1)';
      })
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "circle circle_" + d.node_id
      });

    //image
    node.append("image")
      .attr("x", -37)
      .attr("y", -37)
      .attr("width", 75)
      .attr("height", 75)
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
        return d.node_img;
      });

    force.on("tick", function() {
      link.attr("x1", function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });

      node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
      });
    });

    function drag(d) {
      var dx = d.orig_x - d.px
          dy = d.orig_y - d.py,
          dd = Math.sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy));
      // am I out of bounds
      if (dd >= d.drag_radius - 55){
        // set to previous values
        d.px = d.last_x;
        d.py = d.last_y;
      }
      // remember previous values
      d.last_x = d.px;
      d.last_y = d.py;
    }
    
    function dragstart(d) {
      // original position
      if (!d.orig_x) d.orig_x = d.x;
      if (!d.orig_y) d.orig_y = d.y;
    
      // draw bounds circle
      d.bounds_obj = svg.append('circle')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + d.orig_x + "," + d.orig_y + ")")
        .attr("r", d.drag_radius)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", "2px");
    }
    function dragend(d) {
      // remove circle and clean-up
      d.bounds_obj.remove();
      d.bounds_obj = undefined;
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, it works as expected with one exception, the limit area circle is moving along with each node, can it (outer circle) be fixed so that node position can not be changed while draging. BTW thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Subrata, you mean that after each drag the bounding circle moves to surround the new position of the node?

Comment: Yes @Mark, the bounding circle.